# Virtual Box 4 and VT-x enable settings

Tags: virtualbox

I attached x64 virtual machine, but when I run it, I got error that VT-x is not available. Hardware virtualization enabled for my machine, I know that there is settings for virtual box for enabling VT-x, but I can't found it in 4.02 version.
How to enable this setting for virtual box?

**UPD**
When I try to create a new virtual machine, x64 version is missing in list of available versions in some reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is under Settings->System->Acceleration Tab. Don't forget to activate it in your BIOS, too.

Comment: I haven't this tab (virtual box 4.02v)

Comment: @Kai maybe update to the recent version, I am using v4.18 under linux.

Comment: @Kai I just googled a bit and that tab should be there. Did you check if vt-x is enabled in your BIOS?

Comment: I enabled hardware virtualization in bios, but I'm not sure if vt-x and hardware virtualization in bios is the same?

Comment: @Kai It should actually be the same. However you should see the tab anyway.

Comment: @Kai if it is still not working and you have updated your vbox, then post a screen which shows your settings->system box.

Comment: I updated to latest version and tab appears at least, but it's greyed out :(. It seems something wrong with machine configuration.

Comment: @Kai Which CPU and mainboard are you using? Generally that means that your CPU doesnt support vt-x, however is it grayed out and checked? Did you try, if it works now?

Comment: I can't even switch to this tab. I ended up with converting hdd image into hyper-v format using `VBoxManage  clonehd`, and this converted image attached to hyper-v and now works perfectly